# Laravel transactions not rollback

Tags: laravel

Trying something like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try
{
  $model = new Model;
  $model->name = $name;
  $model->save();
  
  $another = new AnotherModel;
  $another->id = $model->id;
  $another->value = $value; // here i have a validation exception
  $another->save();

  DB::commit();
}catch( Exception $e )
{
  DB::rollback();
}
```

When a validation exception in `$another->value` is throw the `$another` is not save and `$model` remains saved on database table.

> mysql: 5.6.21
>
> table: InnoDB

Comment: validation exception you mean rules?Does it cause transaction to rolllback?

Comment: Yeah, rules situated in the model class. How rollback if a exception validation (from model class rules) is thrown?

Comment: you first check whether is valid then persist to database

Comment: Are you sure an exception is actually being thrown? Put an echo or something in your `catch` (before the `rollback`) just to make sure.

Comment: Or, just do `try { $model = new Model; $model->name = $name; $model->save(); throw new \Exception('oh no!'); DB::commit(); } catch (\Exception $e) { DB::rollback(); }`. Also, are you sure both tables are InnoDB?

Answer (score 0):

First of all **MyIASM** does not support the rollback and commit, you need to use the **InnoDB** for that. So make sure of it.

And to answer your question the 'b' in rollback is caps 'B'.

```
Change => DB::rollback();

To = > DB::rollBack();
```

It'll work.

Answer (score -2):

Your table engine type should be INNODB, not myisam. myisam does not support transactions, so you can't use commit or rollback.

Check you table engine type:

```
show create table 'table_name';
```

Change your engine type:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ENGINE=INNODB;
```